# Vim `:find` can access `.gitignore` stuff

Tags: neovim

How can I make Vim `:find` command ignore files/folders specified by `.gitignore`? `path` content is `path=.,/usr/include,,,**`

[image: find command can access *.pyc file ignored by .gitignore]